# Rails param hash contain array of array for multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form has a multiple select element like this:

```
<select id="startup_markets" multiple="multiple" name="startup[markets][]" style="width:100%">
  <option value="fashion">Fashion</option>
  <option value="startups">Startups</option>
  <option value="apps">Apps</option>
  <option value="social-media">social media</option>
  <option value="email-marketing">Email Marketing</option>
</select>
```

After submitting the post body looks like this:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryiICoZLa9BoF6eFMx Content-Disposition: form-data; name="startup[markets][]"
>
> fashion
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryiICoZLa9BoF6eFMx Content-Disposition: form-data; name="startup[markets][]"
>
> startups

But on rails I get the markets as an array of array:

```
(byebug) params["startup"]["markets"]
[["fashion", "startups"]]
```

Wasn't it supposed to be just `["fashion", "startups"]`? I'm probably doing something silly here but can't figure out what's wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm working on someone else's project and didn't notice there is a filter setup that manipulates the params hash before reaching controller method. Wasted hours and found the problem within mintues after submitting to SO :@

Answer (score 2):

The select name probably should be `name="startup[markets]"`

Also on the ruby side you can handle by calling [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) method on Array.

```
params["startup"]["markets"].flatten
```

will result in

```
=> ["fashion", "startups"]
```

Comment: Turns out it was a filter that modified the params hash. Thanks for the flatten suggestion though.